# How to set variable in PHP class function

Tags: php, class

I've followed several tutorials on php OOP and how to use get/set functions but can't get my functions to set the class properties. I simplified my code down to the bare bones and it still won't work but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my class code:

```
<?php

// Declare the class
class averageWeather {

public $maxtemperatureforecast;

    public function setAverageWeather() {
        $averageWeather->maxtemperatureforecast = '7';
        $this->averageWeather = $averageWeather;
    } //Close function setAverageWeather

    public function getAverageWeather() {
        return $this->averageWeather;
    }  //Close function getAverageWeather

}  //Close Class averageWeather
```

I then include the class file and call it like so:

```
<?php
include '\classes\averageweather_class.php';
$dailyforecast = new averageWeather();
var_dump($dailyforecast);
```

The var_dump shows me that dailyforecast has a property of maxtemperatureforecast but its value is null. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: @B001ᛦ Ultimately $averageWeather is just meant to be an array which stores the functions output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you call any of the functions?

if you dont run `$dailyforecast->setAverageWeather()` first, it won't be set!

Also, in that function, change to this

```
public function setAverageWeather() {
    $this->maxtemperatureforecast = '7';
}
```

Or, you could make it do that automatically in a constructor

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->maxtemperatureforecast = '7';
}
```

Meaning one less extra call to your code.

Tha last way is to just give it a default

```
public $maxtemperatureforecast = 7;
```

Comment: I was wondering how the set function was getting called! In all the tutorials and examples I've been seeing I haven't seen them call the set function? (Of course I can't find an example now.) The __construct method is working for me. Thank you!